# Django ORM: How to set smallinterger field to auto saved on default value upon save?

Tags: django, orm, modal-dialog

I have pretty obvious question, but I cant find its solution.

How to set Modal instance value to default when we do not provide any?

```
Log(user=user, visible=True).save()
```

works fine.

I want to do this.

```
Log(user=user).save()
```

I want to save the value visible to true always. even if i do not specify one.

Comment: have you tried to set visible=True in your model? so this would be the default. And when you want it to be False just say Log(user=user, visible=False).save()

Answer (score 2):

Probably your model looks like this:

```
class Log(models.Manager):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    visible = models.BooleanField()
```

and now you need to change visible field to:

```
visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: Right, i tried to use default with other fields too, but that selects to ID=1 when i set `default=1`. is there any way that i can select 1st element that i have in my elements?
when i order the elements the `ID=1` might not be the first element.

Comment: Can you rephrase your problem or provide an example? I don't understand your problem.

Comment: for example, i have other field like Department, and I also added default property to it. but it select the default value which have ID=1 from department table. 
i am also applying order_by this causes the ID=1 element to go down the list and still be selected.

Comment: I think you are trying to set default value for foreignkey and you should do it like this: department = models.ForeignKey(Department, default=lambda: Department.objects.get(id=1))